# Route [user.verification.notice] not defined / Override EnsureEmailIsVerified?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I've been trying to implement multiple authentication login and registration is working fine in both group but verification route is not working after user registration. Is there any way possible to do this ?

This is my route

```
Route::group([
                'prefix'    => 'users',
                'namespace' => 'Users',
                'as'        => 'user.'
            ],function(){
                Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
                Route::get('/','Main@index');
                Route::get('/dashboard','Main@index')->name('dashboard');
            });
Route::group([
                'prefix'    => 'admins',
                'namespace' => 'Admins',
                'as'        => 'admin.'
            ],function(){
                Auth::routes();
                Route::get('/','Main@index');
                Route::get('/dashboard','Main@index')->name('dashboard');
            });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `php artisan route:list` from your terminal?

Comment: php artisan route:list Output updated

Comment: you have route named `user.verification.notice` not `verification.notice` so please update the statement that calls it to call the one you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I searched a lot but the only way is to handle by manually so I updated my route and it worked here is the code,

```
Route::group([
                'prefix'    => 'admins',
                'namespace' => 'Admins',
                'as'        => 'admin.'
            ],function(){
                Auth::routes();
                Route::get('/','Main@index');
                Route::get('/dashboard','Main@index')->name('dashboard');
            });

Route::get('email/verify', 'Users\Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Users\Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Users\Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
Route::group([
                'prefix'    => 'users',
                'namespace' => 'Users',
                'as'        => 'user.'
            ],function(){
                Auth::routes();
                Route::get('/','Main@index');
                Route::get('/dashboard','Main@index')->name('dashboard');
            });
```

Also I wonder if it would be much easier and simpler if `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` handles all by itself then only thing we've to manage is **show method** in `VerificationController`, I hope they update this issue in upcoming Laravel versions, but it is also possible that I'm not aware of another way to do it, any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: In november 2021 `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); `already handles all. But is necessary add the array:  `['verify' => true]`.

Answer (score 1):

So this was alternately addressed here

[Laracasts::Setting Email Verification Middleware route](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/setting-email-verification-middleware-route?page=0)

Turns out passing the redirectToRoute can be done via the middleware.

```
$router->middleware(['auth:apiuser', 'verified:api.verification.notice'])
```

A real world example

```
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@showProfile')->middleware('verified:admin.verification.notice');
```