# email verification with laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

so im having this problem with laravel 5.7 im trying to build a verification email script
when a new test jobseeker singup the verification email get sent to mailtrap. normaly the verification script should pick the test jobseeker ID from database but the problem is inmail trap the link it doesnt show up correctly (wrong ID)

http://127.0.0.1:8000/job_seeker.verification/**1566934249**?signature=a70c7846941347109945c2e9d07ccbcd285082e3b1f561d15e4b86d3afceb467

the area with bold text is where the correct id is supposed to be

https://github.com/moussa03/job_board

this is the link of the whole project in case anyone wanted to have a look at it any help would be much appreciated

i have tried this solution linked bellow
[Apply Laravel 5.7 MustVerifyEmail on Multiple Authentication System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186788/apply-laravel-5-7-mustverifyemail-on-multiple-authentication-system)

the whole project exists in github

no error message pop up just havin issu with picking the new user id withing the verification link

Comment: Try to remove this line from your routes: `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` because otherwise I think your verification route gets overrided

Comment: no it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$company = new Company;
    if($request->input('website') != ""){
        $company->website = $request->input('website');
    }
    $company->name = $request->input('name');
    $company->type = $request->input('type');
    $company->city = $request->input('city');
    $company->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $company->varificationcode = sha1(time());
    $company->profile_description = "No description";
    $company->user_id = $user->id;
    $company->save();

    Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send(new VarifyMail($company));
```

and inside the Email template I have accessed the company data like this:

```
  <h2 id="greet">Welcome {{$user->name}} to MyCompany</h2>
  <br/>
  <p class="lead">Thank you for registering to our website. It's an honor to have you in our community.</p>
  <br/>
  <p class="lead">Your account has been successfully created. in order to be able to login for the first time, click the link below to activate your account.</p>
  <br/>
  <a class="btn btn-sucess pl-5 pr-5" href="{{url('company/verify',[$user->id ,$user->varificationcode])}}">Verify Email</a>
```